# s3 redirect routing limit, can it be changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a redirect XML document which I plan to use in S3 static web site hosting. I have lots of old URLS that need to be redirected.
When I paste the script in, I get:

```
 the number of routing rules in a website configuration is limited to 50
```

Why is the limit only 50?
Can this be changed?

Comment: There are at least two different workarounds for the limit.  Can you describe the redirection you're doing?  For example, are the requests redirecting to a target where the URLs will be similar but with a prefix added or removed (example, `/images/cat.jpg` in the bucket goes to to `/images/funny/cat.jpg` in the same bucket, or on a different server)?

Comment: Thanks for the info. After looking at what you provided, I used the prefix approach and that resolved my issue. Can you post that as the answer please.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Any chance you could point me to some more documentation around these workarounds? I'm having a similar issue but with trailing slashes. Thanks.